# How Do I Find The Mobile Provider From 4G Dongle?

Tags: linux, command-line, usb, modem, pppd

I have two or more 4G dongles connected via USB. I have set up multiple configuration files (one for each provider), but short of a visual inspection (which for this project won't be possible in the field) I have no way of knowing which SIM in which dongle is connected to which mobile provider.

Is there a way of interrogating the dongle from the command line - perhaps using the *chat* command - to ask it which mobile provider it is connected to?  Obviously smartphones can do this - they display it, after all.  Would this be possible with a dongle?

By the way, this would be *before* telling the modem to connect to the provider's APN, so I can then call *pppd* with the provider-appropriate config file.

Comment: What operating system(s) are you using?

Comment: Linux, which is why I posted it here. :)

Comment: We have a variety of Unices here, so it helps to narrow it down.

Comment: And what dongle do you have? Most support AT commands (extended with a lot of custom stuff). In which case, go get its (possibly "confidential") manual. But I once had a 4G dongle that was running itself some version of linux+busybox and working as an actual router -- if presented itself as CDC device no different from an android phone in tethering mode. I could get into it by "exploiting" the php(!) scripts from its web configuration interface ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/network-information-automaticmanual-selection/).  The command to send to the modem is *AT+COPS?*. The response will be something like

```
+COPS: 0,0,”Verizon Wireless”,7
OK
```

I just need to write some scripting now to automate this.